# Connecting WSO2 appm and EMM SSO with external server

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, mdm

In EMM and in Appmanager can we connect SSO config from external server.If yes than what changes need to be made.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to do login to the management console of EMM and App Manager using an external server?

Comment: Not only login to management console but other also like store,publisher also of App-manager and EMM.

Answer (score 1):

Here how to configure EMM[1] and App Manager[2] with SSO

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/General+Server+Configurations#GeneralServerConfigurations-SSOconfigurations

[2] -https://docs.wso2.com/display/APPM110/Configuring+with+an+External+Identity+Server